# Compute $\frac{4}{5}\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{v^2-2 v\cos\theta+1}\>v{\rm d}v\, {\rm d}\theta$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, multiple-integral, change-of-variable

The integral

$$I=\frac{4}{5}\pi \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{v^2-2 v\cos\theta+1}\>v{\rm d}v\, {\rm d}\theta$$

arises from the calculation of the expected distance between two random points inside a unit circle. Can't figure out the change in variables to transform it to

$$I=\frac{4}{5}\pi \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2(1+\cos2\theta')}} v'^2\,{\rm d}v'\,{\rm d}\theta'$$
[Change of  variable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946673/expected-distance-between-two-points-inside-unit-circle)

${}$

Comment: In the other thread, Orion explains between those two formulas what they did, which was to move the origin and rescale the circle.

Comment: Hi Paul, I don't quite follow the transformation between the formulas. Could you please describe in more detail?

Comment: A better way to get clarification on an existing answer would be to simply add a comment to that answer asking @orion what they meant.

Comment: Ideally, I would do that but I need a reputation of 50 in order to post a comment on other questions. Hope you understand.

Comment: Actually, the @ sign I put before their name should have resulted in a notification to them, so I was hoping they would chime in (since their user profile had indicated activity earlier in the day). However, I have realized what they did. It was poorly explained, so I can't blame you for being confused. It isn't the "center" of the circle they move to the edge, but rather the origin of the polar coordinate system. They are still integrating over the same circle, but now that circle is centered at $v'=1, \theta' = 0$ instead of the previous $v= 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Referring to the graph above, the variable changes used are

$$v = \sqrt{{v'}^2-2{v'}\cos\theta'+1},\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\frac{\sin\theta}{\sin\theta'}=\frac{v'}{v}
$$

Then, according to the Jacobian determinant

$$dv d\theta = \frac{v'}{v}dv' d\theta'$$

with the ranges $\theta'\in[-\frac\pi2, \frac\pi2]$ and $v'\in [0, \sqrt{2(1+\cos2\theta')}]$. Thus,
the integral is transformed to

$$I=\frac{4}{5}\pi \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\int_0^{\sqrt{2(1+\cos2\theta')}} v'^2\,{\rm d}v'\,{\rm d}\theta'=\frac{128\pi}{45}$$